# How to write integration Tests for modals

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rspec, xmlhttprequest

I have searched around the web on how to write integration tests for modals without success.
I am using Rspec. The code works fine, and in my browser the modals are rendered properly

my controller tests are passing and the code is here

```
describe "GET #failed" do
  it "renders the failure status view" do
    @tool = FactoryGirl.create(:tool)
    xhr :get, :failed, { :id => @tool.id, :format => 'js' }
    response.should render_template :failed
  end
end
```

but the integration tests are not working and the code is here

```
describe "rendering the failure status modal", :xhr => true, :js => true do
  before{ click_link 'false'}
  it {should have content('Failure')}
end
```

currently the tests are not passing and this is the error. I have researched about it before
and all the solutions never worked

```
1) Tools Management Page 
 rendering the failure status modal 
 Failure/Error: before { visit '/tools' }
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
 Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux).
 Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path 
 manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=
```

I have not found a working solution for integration tests for modals

Comment: Selenium is unable to locate firefox. Have you tried setting the path like the error message suggests?

Comment: @Sharagoz it should not be dependant on any specific browser, as this is a test. however i did try to set up as specified in the different links and it was not helpful

Comment: Selenium is about browser automation. Selenium-webkit will open a browser and run the tests through it, and will need an actual browser to do that. If you'd rather run integration tests without a full blown browser, then you could perhaps look into using the headless `capybara-webkit` instead.

Comment: am actually doing development using vagrant, therefore there is no browser. so I need something that will run that kind of test @Sharagoz

Answer (score 1):

The default javascript driver for Capybara is Selenium, which requires a browser to work.

Have a look at [poltergeist](http://rubygems.org/gems/poltergeist) which is a capybara driver for [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).  Phantomjs is a headless browser, that's great for running integration tests that need Javascript.